# What is the correct term for being the first to play in a turn-based game?

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following expressions is the most adequate for a turn-based computer game to inform the user (regardless of whether the user is a player or a spectator) that the white player will be the first player to make a move?

- *White starts.*
- *White begins.*
- *White plays first.*
- *White goes first.*
- Something else I haven’t thought of?

Comment: I’m not sure why that is important, but sure, it’s Backgammon (a two-player turn-based board game very much like chess, checkers, etc., except which player starts/begins/plays first/goes first is different each game.)

Comment: There's no ***one*** satisfying answer to this. However, I would prefer *White plays first.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idiomatically, *White begins* is less likely than any of OP's other suggestions, but they're all acceptable.

In football and similar games, *White kicks off* also occurs, and this particular expression is often "figuratively" extended to other contexts (not necessarily even involving *competition* - for example, the first person to address the group in a business meeting).

But one important point to note here is that all these examples use the relevant verb in *simple present* tense. That form would usually only be used by a "commentator" describing what's happening at the *precise moment the game/procedure is actually starting*.

In practice, a commentator is unlikely to describe such an event *as it happens* (except possibly in a *radio* broadcast), because it's normally obvious to the audience anyway. It's much more likely the commentator will be speaking *before* the start of play, telling the audience which "player" ***will*** start the process. The most common way of saying who is *about to start* uses an "infinitive" verb form...

> *"Now we'll watch the final game. White **to start**"* (or *to play [first]*, etc.)

With a relatively slow-moving "turn-based" game (chess, snooker, etc.), most of the time no play is actually taking place (one player is *deciding* his next move). The speaker will thus frequently pepper his commentary with *"White to play"* to keep the audience informed (*to play **next*** is implied, but not normally specified). Also note that in terms of strict grammar the "tensed" verb ***is*** has been "deleted" from an underlying *"White is to play first"* (which is syntactically correct, but not what we normally say).

---

I've been discussing usage from the perspective of a "non-playing, third-party commentator". But it's quite normal for the infinitive usage above to occur when the only people in the conversation are two backgammon players, for example,...

> *"Okay, you won that game. Let's play again. Me **to start**"*

---

Noting @Maulik's comment expressing a preference, I'd just underline a distinction native speakers would normally make. Both the following are quite common utterances...

> 1: *"White plays first"*
>    2: *"White to start"*

...but normally, #1 would be used when describing the rules of a game (chess, for example). When referring to an actual game which is about to start, #2 is far more common - normally with a *named* player (the chess player with the white pieces *always* makes the first move, and the audience would normally be expected to know this).

Comment: @StoneyB: Idiomatically I'd be okay with *"You to break off"* before e.g. a game of backgammon, but I might be more attuned to that usage than the average Anglophone (on account of long-term interest in darts and snooker, where they *are* used "naturally").

Comment: ...also note that ***to open*** might be a bit iffy in the context of who plays first in a game of contract bridge. If the first player *passes*, the second player (dealer's partner) might actually be the one that makes the opening bid. But mostly yeah - it's another replacement term.

Comment: In pool we say *You to break* cisatlantically. In baseball, the first player to bat in each half-inning is said to *lead off*.

Comment: @StoneyB: The idiomatically preferred verb does often seem to be context-specific. You invariably *open* in cricket, *kick off* in football, *serve* in tennis, for example. But thinking about, say, *golf*, I'm not sure there *is* a term for "play first". There ought to be one for *curling* though, because it makes a difference to the subsequent play who started.